# Can I edit multiple models in ASP.NET MVC using Partial Views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm struggling with a concept that would be easy in webforms.  So, if I have a Customer class, and a Customer has an Address, how can I edit both the Customer and Address on the same form in the same submit action?  I would like to create an '_Edit' partial view for the Address, but I don't know how to wire the controller up if there is no submit button for the Address.  I just want a single button to save all the Models in a single View.

So, I could create a new CompanyView model, view, and controller and do it that way.  However, if I have many objects having Addresses it seems like a lot of work to keep creating View Models to allow you to edit both the object and the address in the same form.  Is there a way to create an Address partial edit view and somehow update the Address fields in the Company Edit Controller?  Or, have it somehow pass the model.Address back to the Company Edit Controller instead of null?

*Edit:*

**Models**

```
public class Address
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address 1")]
    public String Address1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address 2")]
    public String Address2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public String City { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public String State { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
    public String PostalCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public String Country { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public Int32 AddressId { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

**Address _Edit Partial View**

```
@model Models.Address

<div class="well">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Address</legend>

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address2)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostalCode)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Country)
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Company Edit View**

```
@model Models.Company

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/ContentLayout.cshtml";
}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2>Edit Company</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Company", new { @class = "bs-example form-horizontal" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressId)

    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Address/_Edit.cshtml", Model.Address)

        <p>
            <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Submit</button>
        </p>
}

    </div>
</div>
```

**Company Edit Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Company model, int id)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // model.Address = NULL here!

                Success("Record updated!");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For model binding to work properly, you need to post only a `Company` back to your controller. Just pass your whole model onto your partial :

```
@model Models.Company

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/ContentLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2>Edit Company</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Company", new { @class = "bs-example form-horizontal" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressId)

            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Address/_Edit.cshtml", Model)

            <p>
                <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Submit</button>
            </p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

**_Edit**

```
@model Models.Company

<div class="well">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Address</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.Id)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Address1)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Address2)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.City)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.State)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.PostalCode)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Country)
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Company model, int id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // model.Address should now be available

        Success("Record updated!");
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

You should now see the `Address` navigation property of your model properly bound on post.

---

**Edit based on question in comment**

How you set up your views and partials is up to you really. The important thing to remember is that model binding works based on the names given to the form elements by the HTML helpers.

So `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)` will result in `<input name="Id">` while `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address.Id)` will result in `<input name="Address.Id">`. First one won't be picked up by the model binder as a navigation property of `Company`, second one will.

The simple route would be to just duplicate your partial view. But if it gets to the point where your partial becomes quite large and complex with a high amount of fields, you could create a partial base class that both your entities inherit of.

BaseEntityWithAddress.cs

```
public partial class BaseEntityWithAddress
{
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Customer.cs

```
public class Customer : BaseEntityWithAddress
{
    // your properties, no need to redefine Address here
}
```

Vendor.cs

```
public class Vendor: BaseEntityWithAddress
{
    // your properties, no need to redefine Address here
}
```

And then your partial view would take `BaseEntityWithAddress` as a model to which you would still pass the whole model.

_Edit.cshtml

```
@model Models.BaseEntityWithAddress

<div class="well">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Address</legend>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.Id)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Address1)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Address2)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.City)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.State)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.PostalCode)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Country)
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And that will generate form elements with the correct names for the model binder to pick up.

Comment: Ok, that works!  So, let's say I have a Customer and Vendor, both needing an Address, your saying you would duplicate the '_Edit' view for both the Customer and Vendor?  Would you name these _EditCustomer and _EditVendor or just _Edit?  Is there a way to write a generic partial edit view for Address so that I only have 1 partial edit view for all the objects that have an Address?

Comment: @Sephrial that was a long answer to type out in a comment, so I've edited my original answer to show you how that would be done.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation!  This helped me wrap my head around model binding.

Comment: what if Company has multiple addresses?  And they are saved as a collection of Addresses in the Company model?   How will the partial know which one to load?

Answer (score 1):

So you would have 2 classes:

```
class Address
{
    public string street {get;set;}
    public string state {get;set;}
}

class Customer
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Address address {get;set;} // links to the above class.
}
```

your main customer view would be something like:

```
@model Models.Customer

@using (Html.BeginForm() 
{

   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)

   @Html.Partial("_Edit", Model.address)

   <button type="submit">Submit</button>

}
```

your partial:

```
@model Models.Address

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.street)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.state)
```

then in your controller:

```
public ActionResult customer(Customer model)
{
    // do whatever

}
```

Comment: This is what I tried to do pretty much, except when I inspect the Customer model in the controller.  model.Address is null.

Comment: It's useful to add what you've tried to your question. That way people get a better understanding of where you're at.